# Python strptime not parsing time zone EST %z

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-3.7, strptime

I am trying to parse the string '10/23/2019 6:02:05 PM EST' into a datetime with time zone using Python 3.7.

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime
timestamp = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z')
```

Error:

```
ValueError: time data '10/23/2019 6:02:05 PM EST' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z'
```

When I create a datetime and output it using the same formatting I get the correct output. The only difference is that there is a 0 in front of the hour, but adding 0 in front of the 6 in my date string results in the same error.

My current solution is to parse the datetime without the timezone and then localize it, but this is not ideal.

````
date_lst = date.split()
date_str = ' '.join(date_lst[0:3])
timestamp = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
new_tz = pytz.timezone(date_lst[3])
timestamp_tz = new_tz.localize(timestamp)```
````

Comment: It seems like this formatting works with UTC, but not other time zones (have tried EST, CST, IST)

Answer (score 0):

It is reasonable to expect that parsing a string with a timezone included would produce a timezone aware datetime object.

Answer (score -1):

Try it

```
>>timestamp = datetime.strptime('10/23/2019 6:02:05 PM EST', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p EST')

>>2019-10-23 06:02:05
```

You can try this.

Comment: This ignores the time zone and produces a time zone naive datetime, which will not error out (unless a time zone other than EST is input), but will also not pass the timestamp correctly because it is not passing the time zone.